# Make file array print deafult names in Java?

Tags: java

My problem is when I print the files within the directory, it prints out stuff like 'thumbs.db' and 'desktop.ini'. How to i make it print the name itself. All the files are .png by the way

```
static File overlayPath1 = new File(Minecraft.getMinecraft().mcDataDir, "\\TVMod\\" + filesList[0].getName());
```

Comment: Can't you just print the substring of the file name by removing the last four characters?

Comment: Java's doing exactly what you asked it to - give you a list of files in the directory. It's not Java's job to decide which files are relevant and which aren't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`thumbs.db` and `desktop.ini` are both files in this directory, but normally in Windows they're hidden. However, because they're still there, they'll show up in your `fileList`.

If you don't want to use these files, you're going to have to skip them somehow. The implementation I'd suggest is to convert it to an `ArrayList`, then remove elements that don't match the `.png` extension.

However, without knowing more about your implementation, though, I can't easily suggest a way to do this.

Comment: Thanks, 1 & 2 were thumbs.db and desktop.ini, and the .png files started at 2